# Retrieve python object with matlab

Tags: python, matlab, pickle

I have pickled a dictionary with python.
I want to use the values of this dictionary on a matlab code.
Is this possible?

Comment: Looks like this has been discussed before on the Mathworks forums http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/290116.  Also a google search gave plenty of Json parsers for Matlab.

Comment: Is it possible to go back into your python code and save the dictionary using `scipy.io.savemat` instead?

Comment: If absolute speed and memory are not concerns, why not just write them to file in python then process them in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries in Matlab can be used in following way:

```
keys={'a','b','c'};
values={5,6,7};
c = containers.Map(keys,values);
c = 

  containers.Map handle
  Package: containers

  Properties:
        Count: 3
      KeyType: 'char'
    ValueType: 'double'
```

So you can generate a .m file from python like following (considering both key and values are real numbers ) :

```
keys="keys = {"+",".join([str(k) for k in python_dict])+"};" 
values="values = {"+",".join([str(python_dict[k]) for k in python_dict])+"};" 
fh=open("mfile.m","w") 
fh.write("%s\n%s\n" % (keys,values)) 
fh.write( "c = containers.Map(keys, values);\n")  
fh.close()
```

And later you can load this file in Matlab.